# Executing a Callback Function After Variable Is Set

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have a page with four tabs and on click on each tab presents me with a grid on the page.

I have a situation where all the tabs clicked within a fraction of second a condition is not getting evaluated. So, I want to execute a set of statements only after "**outer width of the grid is set**".
How do I do it in JQuery?
I tried this:

```
$.when($('#' + dynamicTabId).width() > 0).done(function () {
   
  //Load the corresponding grid of a tab
});
```

Now , the problem is even if `"$('#' + dynamicTabId).width() > 0"` is false, still the callback function is getting executed. Is there any way to wait for it?

I can't use deferred objects because, the tab ids are dynamic, in the same function all the execution is taking place and in a single variable all the id's are getting assigned.

Comment: Is there a function which will set the width of the outergrid

Comment: No , i have to read it from the Dom and wait until it's loaded